# How to Save a compressed image in New folder

Tags: java

```
Compressor.getDefault(this)
 .compressToFileAsObservable(actualImage)
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(new Action1 < File > () {
  @Override
  public void call(File file) {
   compressedImage = file;    
  }
 }, new Action1 < Throwable > () {
  @Override
  public void call(Throwable throwable) {
   showError(throwable.getMessage());
  }
 });
```

When image compressed its does not show in my storage,My image saving path is:

`/data/user/0/com.example.compressor/cache:Compressor/IMG_20190421_111936.jpeg`

I want to save image in Phone Storage.

Comment: Can you explain more about your question? and Please Write code in Question what you have done so for?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a **`:`** in the file path.

Comment: I am able to create `test:file` on linux and `>pwd : /home/axelH/test:file` so this might not be the problem